# Spark Partition By Column- Memory Explosion

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I am trying to partition a parquet by multiple columns. I do this by first creating the partition values through a set of functions, i.e-

```
dataset.withColumn('p_year', functions.year(dataset.col('event_date')))
dataset.withColumn('p_month', functions.month(dataset.col('event_date')))
... etc
```

Then partitioning the RDD using `keyBy`

```
RDD<Tuple2<String, Row>> rddParts = dataset.rdd().keyBy(new BigDumbFunction());

...

class BigDumbFunction implements Function1<Row, String>, Serializable {

    private MySchema schema;

    public BigDumbFunction(MySchema schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(Row row) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for(AbstractPartitionRule abstractPartitionRule: schema.getPartitionRules()) {
            String fieldName = abstractPartitionRule.getField();
            int fieldIndex = row.fieldIndex(fieldName);
            String value = row.getString(fieldIndex);

            stringBuilder.append(fieldName);
            stringBuilder.append("=");
            stringBuilder.append(value);
            stringBuilder.append("/");
        }

        return stringBuilder.substring(0, stringBuilder.length()-1);
    }
}
```

This results in an RDD tuple where the first value is the partition value and the second is the row. It's not actually grouped an I have to do that manually- which makes me think `keyBy` isn't the right function to use.

To actually group them, I look through the rows and sort them by the key-

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Row>> jrows = rddParts.toJavaRDD();
Map<String, List<Row>> siftedRows = new HashMap<>();

jrows.foreach((jrowTuple) -> {
    String partitionName = jrowTuple._1();
    Row rowData = jrowTuple._2();

    if (!siftedRows.containsKey(partitionName)) {
        siftedRows.put(partitionName, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    siftedRows.get(partitionName).add(rowData);
});
```

Doing `foreach` or `collect` here will blow out the memory to 1gb or more. I'm assuming this is because I'm adding it to a Map which can't have the same optimizations as the RDD.

How can I partition by multiple columns with the least amount of memory as possible? Could I build a single partition column with all of the partition values and do a filter by distinct?

Comment: Do you need to have the actual value of the partition key as a column? Datasets have the `repartition()` method which allows you to specify one or more columns (or column expressions) to partition by.

Comment: I don't think I understand repartition correctly. It looked like it wasn't partitioning by columns but just chunking the results into multiple files. There is a `partitionBy` that does take keys, but it seems to be pretty inefficient memory wise- hence my switch to manual RDD partitioning. Am I mistaken on `repartition()`?

Comment: `repartition()` is a method on `Dataset` and it only shuffles data in memory such that rows with same partition key end up in the same partition. `partitionBy()` is a method on `DataFrameWriter` that makes file-based writers place their files in a partitioned directory structure. If the data is not properly partitioned before that, `partitionBy()` will shuffle the data first. It is not clear from your question which of those two you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't see how running an action such as `foreach()` or `collect()`, which brings all the data into the driver program, could be a faster or more memory-efficient way to repartition.

Comment: You're right. `foreach()` and `collect()` are not more efficient. I think the solution is to use only the columns to build the partition combination necessary- `dataset.select(colsArray).dropDuplicates().collect()`- and then with that information filter out partitions by the unique combinations of partitions. I think that will avoid loading the datasets into memory. I'll try that and update on what I find.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you try to explain what exactly your final goal is.

Comment: I want to partition out the results by columns into the filesystem. ex: `p_year=2019/p_month=10/p_day=10/asdf.parquet`. When I use the tools available for repartitioning, it uses more memory than I'd like. On a 50mb parquet I can use up to 1gb of memory when the shuffle happens. I want to repartition to the filesystem by column using the least amount of memory possible.

Comment: Actually, `partitionBy()` does not shuffle but instead sorts the records in each partition before writing it to the storage in a partitioned fashion. How much is your data? Parquet files are generally compressed and can be much smaller than the actual data if the latter contains many repeating values.

Comment: A 50mb file contains about 500k rows. Using the method I described early I was able to repartition a 200mb parquet file in ~600mb